# Installing Magento in a subdirectory vs root (public_html)

Tags: magento, hosting

What are the pros and cons of installing Magento in a subdirectory on a web hosting?

Comment: Future upgrades stink if you install Magento in the document root. It's an issue I wish I'd corrected a long time ago.